# Code to add two 4-bit integers with verilog doesn't work. What is wrong?

Tags: verilog, xilinx, hdl, intel-fpga, quartus

I have a code that adds two 4 bit numbers; unfortunately it is not working for every case even though the formulas are really simple and I don't find the problem...

```
module part2(SW, LEDG, LEDR);

    input [17:0] SW;
    output [17:0] LEDR;
    output [4:0] LEDG;

    //Red lights for each one
    assign LEDR[17:0] = SW[17:0];

    //Wires between adders.
    wire carry[2:0];

    //Add the first digits of A and B
    full_adder F0(SW[4], SW[0], SW[8], LEDG[0], carry[0]);
    //Add the second digits of A and B
    full_adder F1(SW[3], SW[1], carry[0], LEDG[1], carry[1]);
    //Add the third digits of A and B
    full_adder F2(SW[6], SW[2], carry[1], LEDG[2], carry[2]);
    //Add the last digits of A and B
    full_adder F3(SW[7], SW[3], carry[2], LEDG[3], LEDG[4]);

    endmodule

module full_adder(A, B, CI, S, CO);

    input A, B, CI;
    output S, CO;

    //Sum
    assign S = A ^ B ^ CI;

    //Carry out
    assign CO = (A & B) | (CI & A) | (CI & B);

endmodule
```

It seems to work for most cases but look what happens with 1 and 10 or 10 and 10:

[image]

Comment: The problem was  with wire carry[2:0] instead of  wire [2:0]carry

Comment: `wire carry [2:0]` vs `wire [2:0] carry` will not make a difference in this situation. `wire [2:0] carry` means `carry` is a packed array (also known as a vector), you can access all bits together, individually or a slice. `wire carry [2:0]` is an unpacked array of single bits, meaning you can access any index, but not the array as a whole or slice.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `A` is mapped to `SW[7:4]` and `B` to `SW[3:0]`. Then the problem is in the `F1` instance; `SW[3]` should be `SW[4]`.

```
full_adder F1(SW[ 4 /*not 3*/ ], SW[1], carry[0], LEDG[1], carry[1]);
```